# Admob native express ads in listview disappear

Tags: android, listview, admob, native-ads

I am using express ads in my listview. I have my custom adapter in which I get an array of objects. Objects can be 2 different types (One my own class other NativeExpressAdView).

I create adView this way:

```
NativeExpressAdView adView = new NativeExpressAdView(activityContext);
    AdSize adSize =  new AdSize(AdSize.FULL_WIDTH, 150);
    adView.setAdSize(adSize);
    adView.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.ad_unit_id));
    adView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            adSize.getHeightInPixels(activityContext)));

    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(request);
```

And then in my adapter I show it like this(If object is type of NativeExpressAdView):

```
 convertView = (NativeExpressAdView) getItem(position);
return convertView;
```

The problem is this:

- I get the ad
- I get a new item in my array
- listview updates
- ad changes position (everything is ok)
- I get a new item in my array list
- listview updates
- ad changes position but disappears (I can see only gray background on which I can click and it opens the ad but no text or buttons)
- after a couple more items it reappears and then it stays as it should be.

Can someone tell me why it disappears (usually(but not always) after second new item)?

Edit:

after some more testing I found out that it does not disappear but its position goes out of the view for some time then once its back in it stays ok.
Here is a picture of what I mean:

[image]